# Can't find org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, org.json

I'm working on a Java project that uses the `org.json.JSONObject` package. However, whenever I use it in eclipse, it says that no such package was found. However, when I develop on android i.e. create a new Android project in eclipse, I can use it without doing anything (no add external JARs and stuff), so I'm pretty sure that the required JAR is on my machine.

However, searching for "org.json", "*json*jar", "json*jar" over my entire filesystem did not return anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not develop for android, but it looks like that [class is part of that SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for Android. I am not sure if it is the exact same class or not, but json.org has a class with the same name and package [here](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) or you can pick a different one to use from the Java list [here](http://www.json.org/).